# Can't reach WAMP server with WAN IP

Tags: wamp, wampserver

I'm trying to access my WAMP server through my WAN IP.

My network infrastructure consists of a ISP's modem and a wireless router. Using win7.

I have setup the WAMP server on my laptop. I connected my laptop directly to my ISP's modem with a Ethernet cable and received the IP address 91.105.100.XXX. I was then able to connect to my WAMP server through this IP.

I disconnected my laptop form the modem and connected my modem to the wireless router. Then I connected with my laptop to the wireless network and tried to use the same IP address 91.105.100.XXX to access the WAMP server.

It was working for a while ~10 minutes. When joined to the wireless network I obtained another IP address - 46.109.65.XX. I tried to connect to the WAMP server using the new IP address 46.109.65.XX, but was unsuccessful. I am not able to reach the WAMP server when I’m connected to the wireless network through the WAN IP. Localhost works fine.

I have enabled port forwarding in my wireless routers configuration.
Tried to turn off firewall - no succes.
http://www.whatsmyip.org/port-scanner/server/ - show's that all ports are timed out.

Maybe I am doing something wrong or am I missing something?
Thanks for the help in advance.

**UPDATE**

I discovered that the main problem is with my 80 port, that doesn't want to work. When I use the port 8080 in configuration everything works fine. I even installed IIS and discovered the same problem. Both ports are forwarded in the routers configuration. I have a TL-WR740N router. After looking around for a while in settings I noticed that the routers web management port was set to 80, so I changed it. But the problem persists.

Comment: The local network ip works fine, but I want others to be able to connect to my site from outside.

Answer (score 0):

The modem is what talks to your ISP and therefore it is the modem that will be allocated a WAN IP address.

The router has a little DHCP server running in it and this will dynamically allocate IP addresses to your internal hardware as they power up their network cards. This could be your problem as when you were connected directly to the router your Laptops IP Address would have been 91.105.100.XXX but now it will be something like 192.168.X.Y.

So to run a server on the laptop you must configure it to NOT USE the DHCP allocated internal IP address or your port forwarding will only work if your laptop luckily gets the same internal ip address from the router each time you reboot the laptop.

So go to Control Panel -> Network and Sharing Center -> Change Adapter settings. This should get you to the `Network Connections` page of control panel.

Left click on the icon for your Wireless Network Connection and select Properties from the dropdown menu. On the properties dialog double click the `Internet protocol version 4 (TCP/IPv4)` line in the list to load the Properties dialog.

If you see a checkbox called `Obtain an IP Address automatically` and it is checked you are getting your ip address from the routers DHCP server.

Click the `Use the following ip address` checkbox and enter a valid ip address in the subnet range that your router is configured to allocate. It probably something like 192.168.0.x. Its a good idea here to check with the admin pages of your router, find what range the router is allocating and also there is normally a way of telling the DHCP server to allocate ip's from a range, for example it could be 192.168.0.100 to 192.168.0.200. This is the number range that dynamically allocated ips will come from, so you want to pick an ip for your laptop that is not between 100 and 200 so for example lets say 192.168.0.10. They do this expressly so you can setup servers with static ip address's. Some manufacturers leave high numbers for servers and some leave low numbers, so check your router.

It should look something like this, BUT CHECK YOUR OWN ROUTERS NUMBER RANGE!

[image]

Now your laptop is setup you now need to go and redo the port forwarding so that any communication on port 80 from the outside world is forwarded to port 80 on the static ip address you have just allocated to your laptop. Now comms should flow through the router to yout laptop.